# Convert IP Address from std::string to boost::uint32

Tags: c++11, boost

Is there any function in the Boost library, in which I can convert and IPv4 address given as string:

```
std::string ip_address = "192.168.0.1";
```

Into a binary format as following "11000000101010000000000000000001" and store it in a boost::unit32 unit, or I should build the function by myself?

Also what about converting an IPv6 address from std::string into 4 * unit32, is there any function to convert it into octets?

Comment: What about IPv6 addresses?

Comment: I edited, and I meant the same like IPv4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/asio/) will get you there, as in:

```
boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("192.168.0.1").to_ulong();
```

IPv6 is a little more complicated, as you have to use `boost::asio::ip::address_v6::from_string(addr).to_bytes()` which returns a `boost::array<unsigned char, 16>` and convert from that yourself.

Comment: note that to_ulong return in host order, while to_ubyte return in network byte order